# Differences between WebAssembly.Authentication and WebAssembly.Msal

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

I'm just getting acquainted with Azure authentication and I am already lost at the beginning.

I do not find what is the difference between `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication` and `Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal`.

I can see that first is valid from version 6.0.3 and the last is from 6.0.4 but I do not know why the new one is better than the other and how can I use it.

Please don't give me minus - rather an answer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication`** and **`Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal`** packages provide a set of primitives that help the application to authenticate users and obtain tokens to call protected APIs.

- **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication** provides security with authentication for Blazor WebAssembly apps. This [package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#authentication-package) includes services that can provision access tokens for an application.
- **Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal** provides types for using the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) with Blazor WebAssembly. It authenticates Blazor webassembly applications with Azure Active Directory and Azure Active Directory B2C.

##### Note:

> **The `Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal`package transitively adds the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication`
> package to the app.**

This is why, *Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal* package is better than *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication* package.

- To [install](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/)  **`Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal`**  package include it  like below:

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal -Version 6.0.4
```

- To use **`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication`** package refer the [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

For more information, please **refer** below links:

[Ref1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication?view=aspnetcore-6.0) , [Ref2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.iaccesstokenprovider?view=aspnetcore-6.0) , [Ref3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.authentication.webassembly.msal.models?view=aspnetcore-6.0).